# Rails respond_to issue with json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json

I'm doing some HTML5 uploading and encountering a problem I can't seem to figure out. Take this functioning code:

```
if @image.save
    render :json => {:status => "Successfully uploaded image!"}
else
    render :json => {:status => "Something went wrong with your upload!"}
end
```

That works and it does exactly what it's supposed to. However, when I add respond_to to catch HTML requests, it fails completely (though the HTML portion works.)

```
respond_to do |format|
    if @image.save
        format.html {redirect_to(edit_product_path(@image.product), :notice => "Your image was added successfully.")}
        format.json {render :status => "Successfully uploaded image!"}
    else
        format.html {redirect_to(edit_product_path(@image.product), :alert => "An error occurred while attempting to upload your image. Please try again.")}
        format.json {render :status => "Something went wrong with your upload!"}
    end 
end
```

Any ideas what could be wrong? I feel like I'm overlooking something simple. Thanks.

**EDIT - ISSUE RESOLVED**

I figured it was a stupid thing I kept overlooking. Turns out the request was HTML, not JSON, which was due to the fact that since uploading required the content type to be multipart/form-data the respond_to was triggering HTML.

Comment: Firebug simply shows: 

JSON.parse: unexpected character

return window.JSON.parse( data );

Answer (score 2):

Render expects a status code so the following won't work

```
format.json {render :status => "Something went wrong with your upload!"}
```

You can write it out as

```
format.json {render :error => "Something went wrong with your upload!", :status => :bad_request }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to render response into json

```
# old
format.json {render :status => "Successfully uploaded image!"}

# new
format.json { render(:json => { :status => "Successfully uploaded image!" }) }
```